# Change DIV height dynamically based on viewport height in Drupal 7

Tags: jquery, css, drupal

My page only consist of header and content.  The header is about 90px and all my contents are placed inside a DIV.  Is there a way to change the height of DIV to match the height of my viewport?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$("#id_of_content_div").height($(window).height()-$("#header").height());
```

$(window).height() is the viewport height

to resize content height when resizing the viewport, use

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $("#id_of_content_div").height($(window).height()-$("#header").height());
});
```

Comment: I have another problem .. I created a js file with this code inside

Comment: (function($) {
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".bcontainer").height($(window).height()-$("#header").height());
  });
});
})(jQuery);

Comment: I added the script inside mayo.info .. mayo is the theme I am using .. not sure if I am doing it right?

Comment: Alright the script works, thanks! However, is there a way to automatically change it as soon as I adjust my viewport without reloading the page?

Comment: use:
$(window).resize(function() {
 $(".bcontainer").height($(window).height()-$("#header").height()); 
});

edited my answer to include this code for clarity